# how to create a file in unix while reading from another directory

Tags: bash, shell

I want to copy files from one directory to other. But the issue is , the directory from which i want to copy is Root user. So the permission denaid for copying. Is there any way to copy files from root user folder to other.

Comment: execute the script as root user?

Comment: The user id that's trying to copy the files needs to have read permissions on the files. Either the user id part of the same group id to which the files belong and group id has read permissions (740) or everyone has read permissions (744). The parent dir needs to have read and execute permissions for group/others (755).

Comment: This does not appear to be related to programming as defined in the Stack Overflow posting guidelines. Perhaps ask on [unix.se] or [su] but you really need more details about what is failing. A directory cannot be a user so maybe work on describing the circumstances more adequately, too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is more properly asked on the StackExchange site [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).